# I am trying to make a simple calculator in TASM but I keep getting an error

Tags: assembly, tasm

I get the error: 'Extra character on line' on line 78

This is the part where I get the error:

```
    string db 10,13, "The result is: ", "$"

    some codes here.....

    add_here: 
            mov bl, num2
            mov al, num1
            mov num, al

            mov ah, 09h
(78)        mov dx, offset string
            int 21h
            ret
```

Comment: Look for non-ASCII characters behind "string", which your editor may have hidden.

Comment: Try deleting and retyping the line.

Comment: Try using the instruction "lea dx, string" instead of "mov dx, offset string"